# How to view contents of EhCache cache in production

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, profiler, jconsole

A co-worker told me that it might be possible to use JConsole to view the contents of an EhCache cache at any time in production. I'm wondering: is this true, and if so how/why? And more importantly, would merely peeking at the cache's contents cause performance issues for the app (like starting a profiler would)?